# Unable to change link-local address for tunnel with iproute2

Tags: ubuntu, ipv6, tunneling, iproute2, link-local

I have a couple of HE sit tunnels on Ubuntu 18.04 box.
Only first one works as expected and I suppose the reason is almost same link-local addresses (generated from same MAC).

What I'm trying is to spoof link-local address of next tunnel.

Brand new tunnel:

```
he-ipv6-4@NONE: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1480 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/sit 64.137.65.14 peer 72.52.104.74
    inet6 2001:470:1f04:2ba::2/64 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::4089:410e/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I'm trying to change it with:

```
ip address replace dev he-ipv6-4 scope link fe80::4189:410e/64
ip address flush dev he-ipv6-4
```

After this both (new and old) link-local addresses disappear from 'ip a s' output.
Where I'm wrong?

Comment: `fe80::4089:410e/64` is not a SLAAC address generated from a MAC address.

Comment: @RonMaupin, you're right....  the first created tunnel has this "inet6 fe80::9a10:7e3c/64 scope link", and it looks like generated from MAC, but why fe80::4089:410e/64  like addresses I can see on next created tunnels....

Comment: Well, even `fe80::9a10:7e3c/64` is not a SLAAC address generated from a MAC address. The IID is not 64 bits, nor does it have `ff:fe` in the middle of the IID.

Comment: A more probable reason is that you have your default route set to use the first tunnel (`ip -6 route show`). How do you plan to use both tunnels?